# Any change in deployment methods when changing from Google Container Registry to Artifact Registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I currently deploy my app using the Google Cloud SDK Shell using `gcloud app deploy` after navigating to the folder where my app.yaml is stored. It is a simple Flask app on Python 3.9.

I currently use App Engine and [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/). I am considering migrating to [Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/) as GCR is no longer supported except for critical security updates.

Question: When changing from GCR to GAR will I still be able to use the same deployment method as above or will that need to change as well?

Comment: Yes, follow the instruction in the UI, it's done in a few minutes and works seamlessly.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Sorry to digress which UI are you referring to and is this applicable to app running on cloud run?

Comment: On the UI, you have a migration wizard that set up the exact same behavior between the 2 product and you can safely stop to use container registry without any impact on your current pipeline!!